# JavaFX/FXML: ImageView and labels inside BorderPane not displayed

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, gridpane, borderpane

My problem is that in the following construct, the bold marked images and labels inside a BorderPane inside a GridPane inside a ... aren't displayed. I placed the images and labels inside another BorderPane so each row of the GridPane has more styling options. When only some of the labes are inside a BorderPane, then all labels (both those by themselves and those inside a BorderPane) are displayed but now that all are inside their individual BorderPanes, none are displayed. Setting prefHeight for the BorderPanes didn't make a difference. Any ideas?

Edit: marking something bold doesn't seem to work in a code field. I'm talking about everything on GridPane.rowIndex="0".

Thanks in advance!

**example.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="examplePackage.exampleController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

<VBox>
    <TitledPane>
<!-- ................................................................................... -->
        <graphic>
            <BorderPane prefWidth="1312">
                <left>
                    <BorderPane>
                        <left>
                            <ImageView>
                                <Image url="file:///....png"/>
                            </ImageView>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <Label text="Text" style="-fx-padding:5"></Label>
                        </right>
                    </BorderPane>
                </left>
                <center> 
                </center>
                <right>
                    <BorderPane>
                        <left>
                            <StackPane prefWidth="32">
                                <ImageView>
                                    <Image url="file:///....png"/>
                                </ImageView>
                            </StackPane>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <StackPane prefWidth="28" style="-fx-padding:0,5,0,5; -fx-border-width:0px 0px 0px 0.5px; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color:#ffffff">
                                <ImageView>
                                    <Image url="file:///....png"/>
                                </ImageView>
                            </StackPane>
                        </right>
                    </BorderPane>
                </right>
            </BorderPane>
        </graphic>
<!-- ................................................................................... -->
        <GridPane>
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="5.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="20.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>

            <BorderPane prefHeight="30" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" style="-fx-border-color: rgb(0,0,0); -fx-border-width:0px 0px 0.5px 0px">
                <ImageView>
                    <Image url="file:///....png"/>
                </ImageView>
            </BorderPane>

            <BorderPane GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" style="-fx-border-color: rgb(0,0,0); -fx-border-width:0px 0px 0.5px 0px">
            <Label text="Text">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>
            </BorderPane>

            <BorderPane GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" style="-fx-border-color: rgb(0,0,0); -fx-border-width:0px 0px 0.5px 0px">
            <Label text="Text">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>
            </BorderPane>

            <BorderPane GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" style="-fx-border-color: rgb(0,0,0); -fx-border-width:0px 0px 0.5px 0px">
            <Label text="Text">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>
            </BorderPane>

            <BorderPane GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" style="-fx-border-color: rgb(0,0,0); -fx-border-width:0px 0px 0.5px 0px">
            <Label text="Text">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>
            </BorderPane>

            <Label text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
                </font>
            </Label>

        </GridPane>
<!-- ................................................................................... -->
    </TitledPane>
</VBox>
</BorderPane>
```

**exampleController.java**

```
package examplePackage;

public class exampleController
{

}
```

**Main.java**

```
package examplePackage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("example.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1920,800));
            primaryStage.setTitle("exampleTitle");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided fxml fails to load into the Scene Builder. `java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 92; The string "--" is not permitted within comments.` When fixed I can take a second look.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak My bad, I removed the exclamation marks from the closing tags of the comment lines.

Comment: Easy reproduction is a crucial condition to get help. I still can not import it to Scene Builder. The moment you confirm it is possible I'll take a third look.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak I'm still a beginner and not exactly sure what the scene builder requires for it to work. Above code was just a snippet from a larger fxml file. I edited it again and succesfully tried it out with a different Main and Controller class. I hope that works for you too.

Comment: [mcve] please .. (including controller and boilerplate app)

Comment: @kleopatra I added the controller and Main class. Not sure what you mean by boilerplate app but I start it by simple clicking "run" in Eclipse. I hope that will do.

Comment: @Varest example.fxml is still not valid. I'm afraid that in current state you have to fix it on your own. But I'll try to guide you through a process of doing it. Install [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) and try to recreate only small part of layout that you struggle with. After having it done save the fxml and compare it with example.fxml. If it won't help please edit your question and publish fxml created with Scene Builder and describe precisely the problem. I'm sure I can help then.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak Thanks, by playing around with Scene Builder, I figured out what the problem was. I couldn't just place a label directly inside the border pane. Instead, I had to place it inside the <top/right/bottom/left> part of the pane.

Comment: @Varest Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I placed the labels directly inside the border pane without "" tags to specify their alignment.

**Wrong:**

```
<BorderPane GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
    <Label text="Text">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
        </font>
    </Label>
</BorderPane>
```

**Right:**

````
<BorderPane GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
    <left>
        <Label text="Text">
            <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="13"></Font>
            </font>
        </Label>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```
````